# Efficient edit pandas column values based on column value which is list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

How to EFFICIENTLY (fast way) edit pandas DF column based on a condition on string, where the column values are lists of strings.

eg find all rows with a string from set `{'Adam', 'bbb'}` in df column `string_lists` (which is a list of strings) and remove this strings (`'Adam', 'bbb'`) from the `string_lists` value

ex.

```
id   string_lists
0    ['aaa', 'Adam', 'bbb'] -> ['aaa']
```

EDIT:

I've solved it:

```
drop_options={'?',2, 'abc'}
l1 = [1, '?', 2, 3, 4, 5, 'abc']

print(l1)
print([s for s in l1 if not any(s == drop for drop in drop_options) ])
```

Comment: There is no way of doing this efficiently, at least to pandas standars. Pandas excels at operations that are vectorized. I do not think it is possible to vectorize removing items from lists that are stored in pandas values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply function on df.

```
df['string_lists'] = df.string_lists.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i != 'Adam'])
```

Output:

```
  string_list
0  [aaa, bbb]
```